# How do I modify this loop to list numbers 100 to 1

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Local variable declaration:
    int a = 10;

    // while loop execution
    while (a < 20) 
    {
        cout << "value of a: " << a << endl;
        a++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: You should count down `a` from `100` as long `a > 0` is `true`. Try to explain your rubber duck, what these statements manipulating `a` are doing in the current code.

Comment: Running time backwards is also an option, but very difficult to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Local variable declaration:
    int a = 100;

    // while loop execution
    while (a > 0) 
    {
        cout << "value of a: " << a << endl;
        a--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your loop like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ranges>

namespace sv = std::views;

int main() 
{
    for (int i : sv::iota(1, 101) | sv::reverse)
        std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/besWMb).

Note that this code is only valid from C++20.

Comment: This example is definitely the better solution practically, but it doesn't really build off of/ "modify" OP's code

Comment: @Spyre I see your point, but it is a modification. I think it's worthwhile showing this option as well.

Comment: It is worth mentioning these are c++20 features

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I was hoping to avoid that :p but you're right. Edited, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Strange indentation. (Now fixed)

But a while loop is based on a condition which means you should initialise the variable *a* to be 100.
After this use a loop to check while a is greater than 0. Then in the loops body you can output the variable *a* and decrement the number.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 100;
    while (a > 0) {
        cout << "value of a: " << a << endl;
        a--; // Decrement A
    }
}
```

Another method would be use a for loop

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int a = 100; a > 0; a--) {
        cout << "value of a: " << a << endl;
    }
}
```

These are very simple ways and I'd recommend looking into some books for beginners if you are new to C++ to understand the different syntax of loops.